# PHP date not taking into account AM/PM properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a booking system based on Woocommerce and the [Woocommerce Bookings](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/) plugin. This means essentially I don't have control over the format of the data given to me. At the end of the checkout process I am given a start date and duration for the booking, and I need to display an end date. In theory this is very simple. The data I am given looks like this:

```
Array
(
[Booking Time] => 8:00 am
[Duration] => 5 hours
)
```

No nice timestamps to use but I thought date() could easily handle something like this. Here's the code I've used:

```
date ('h:ia', strtotime(($item['Booking Time'] + $item['Duration'])));
```

This almost works, the problem is in this case it outputs 01:00am when it should obviously be 01:00pm, so it's getting the hour correct but just not understanding the am/pm switch. What is the best solution here given the data structure I'm being given?

Comment: Try to strtotime() booking time and duration independently. Or, you could strtotime() booking time, with date appended (so it's for instance 8:00am 20th Jan 2015), and then calculate duration by multiplying hours with 60 or whatever(if you've got days of duration, multiply by 24 first, you get the point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  `date_add`   to add two times properly:

```
 $date = date_create($item['Booking Time']);
 date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($item['Duration']));
 echo date_format($date, 'h:ia');
```

---

One line solution:

```
date_format(date_add(date_create($item['Booking Time']), date_interval_create_from_date_string($item['Duration'])), 'h:ia');
```

Comment: Works perfectly, was not aware of that function so thanks very much for the answer and enlightenment :)